# Auto sync only when connected to a specific wifi network

Tags: wi-fi, sync, settings, 3g, battery-life

I am getting rather low battery life when using auto-sync on 3G. I have wifi in college and at home, so I'm looking for a way to enable auto sync only when connected to those 2 specific wifi networks.

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63987/how-to-block-apps-on-tablet-from-accessing-the-internet-while-on-tethering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easily accomplished using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). If you don't know, *Tasker* is the most complete automation solution for Android. It doesn't come for free (5 Euro -- but you can get a free trial on their homepage), but is definitly worth the price. Just take a look at the [Tasker UserGuide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/) for a full description.

*Tasker* combines conditions and tasks to profiles. In your case, the *Task* would be something like:

**Task AutoSync:**

- Auto-Sync: On

You will have two *Conditions*, one for each profile (*Tasker* always connects conditions by AND, so you need two different profiles:

- **Profile Home:**

  - *Condition:* Wifi Connected (add your home network's details)
  - *Task:* AutoSync
- **Profile College:**

  - *Condition:* Wifi Connected (add your college's network's details)
  - *Task:* AutoSync

Now, when you're not connected to any of these networks, switch off AutoSync manually *once* (you won't have to repeat this). Next time you connect to one of the two networks, *Tasker* turns AutoSync on -- and resets it to the previous state (off) as soon as you are disconnected.

If *Tasker* is too heavy for you, I'm pretty sure there are other automating tools which can accomplish this simple task ([Llama - Location Profiles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) for example). But now that you've got the idea, you will find the related app fitting you.

Comment: Tasker looks like a really powerful app, but Llama looks like it'll serve my purpose (just this one) and is free. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly why I mentioned both: I use Tasker, so here I was sure about how it works -- and Llama being a free alternative which most likely can do the same for this case. Enjoy :)