# Enable/Disable application-specific settings (updates, upload) for a specific WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, tasker, automation, llama

I would like to automate my android phone to do the following:

```
if connected_to_wifi(ssid=my_mobile_3g_router) then
    (1) disable automatic google play updates
    (2) turn off dropbox camera upload
    (3) enable VPN from no root firewall
else
    enable (1) (2), disable (3)
```

Can `tasker` or `llama automate` do it? I have tried `automate` but I haven't seen application specific settings. I could buy `tasker` if it could handle my case.

The reason should be clear: I travel a lot and being abroad I use 3g wifi mobile router to share Internet with my devices. Unfortunately, for my phone any wifi is seen as a resource without data limit which is not always true.

My question is a bit different but related to: [Auto sync only when connected to a specific wifi network](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35594/auto-sync-only-when-connected-to-a-specific-wifi-network)
In my question, I ask for application-specific settings. The related one is about system sync.

Comment: Which device and Android version are you using? Is it rooted? If rooted, first is [definitely doable](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/137376/96277), I don't use dropbox so can't tell, and if the device is already rooted then AFWall+ firewall can be used (it offers support for multiple profiles which can be easily managed using Tasker).

Comment: I don't want to have it device-specific. I assume, that device is non-rooted, but if there is a solution for rooted devices, I am also happy to see it. 

The question is about changing any setting of any application – I don't want to be forced to change some applications just because they are supported by tasker/any other automation tool.

Comment: "*I don't want to have it device-specific*" -- it won't make the question device-specific but it would help a poster to test and provide a satisfactory answer. For example, one may have to use dumpsys tool to query a service. Not every Android version from all manufacturers would provide same type of output from dumpsys. // Providing Android version and device lessens the scope.

Comment: You're using [this firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall), correct?

Comment: I use Android 5.1.1 on Sony Xperia Z2. 
Edit: yes, I use this firewall. Google Photos upload and Play updates are the most important bits to me

Answer (score 0):

[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) can indeed do what you are looking for!
Using the Wifi-Connected State profile inverted (profile on when *not* connected) you can trigger a task that does the following:

1) Disable Google Play updates via [Synker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.afterhoursdevelopers.android.synker)

In newly created task Add an Action ('+' at bottom, center of screen),  select 'Plugin' category, select Synker, select 'Autosync Settings', select Configuration, uncheck the Google /account name/ App Data)
    Source: [Is there an App Update Scheduler app? Reply #6](http://forums.androidcentral.com/droid-bionic/303853-there-app-update-scheduler-app.html#post3003090)

2) Stop auto-upload of photos using [Dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync&hl=en) (replaces Dropbox built-in tool)

3) Use [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin&hl=en) to connect to stored VPN (requires root)

In newly created task Add an Action (new Action> Plugins> Secure Settings> Root Actions> VPN)
    Source: [VPN Verbindung (keine Zusatzapp) per Tasker starten?](http://www.android-hilfe.de/thema/vpn-verbindung-keine-zusatzapp-per-tasker-starten.566059/#post-7604423)

Comment: Can you please expand your answer? I'm looking for detailed instructions on "*disable automatic google play updates*" and "*enable VPN from no root firewall*"? Have you tested your solution?

Comment: I have tested Parts 1 & 2 at this time. I am unable to test the VPN since I do not have a VPN setup nor is my device (Samsung Galaxy Note 4, Android 5) rooted.

Comment: I think the best solution for that is to mark the concrete Wifi network as metered (treated as 3G). This answer is very complicated (you need to install even more apps!). It shows that tasker and similar tools have still a long way to go.

Comment: Except that marking as metered does not solved #3 in the question. Also, if that solution works, you might want to post it as an answer and accept it.